# calculo de número factorial

Tags: sql

Estoy haciendo una función para calcular el número factorial. Y no me da error de sintaxis, por ejemplo, si pongo el factorial de 3 me devuelve 2, cuando es 6.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS factorial $$
CREATE FUNCTION factorial (n SMALLINT)
RETURNS SMALLINT
BEGIN
DECLARE i SMALLINT ;
SET n=0;
SET i=0;
WHILE n=n*(n-1) DO
SET n=n+i;
SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
RETURN i;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image: ejemplo de uso]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algunos problemas:

- `WHILE n=n*(n-1) DO` se invalida siempre cuando `n=1`, que es la segunda vuelta del ciclo por lo que `i` será 2 y este siempre será el retorno
- Estás usando `n` como parámetro pero dentro de la función lo estás sobreescribiendo cuando haces `SET n=0;`
- Por último no parece para nada una rutina para calcular un factorial

Debiera ser algo así:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS factorial $$
CREATE FUNCTION factorial (n SMALLINT)
RETURNS SMALLINT
BEGIN
    DECLARE suma SMALLINT ;
    DECLARE tmp SMALLINT ;
    SET tmp=n;
    WHILE tmp>0 DO
        SET suma=suma*tmp;
        SET tmp=tmp-1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN suma;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Ten en cuenta algunas cosas:

- Un `SMALLINT` te va a limitar a calcular hasta el factorial de 7 si no me equivoco
- Revisa la función, por que no tuve posibilidad de probarla

Comment: muchas gracias , te ha faltado declarar la i, pero ya lo he corregido.

Answer (score 2):

Coloco esta respuesta como una **opción alternativa** basándome en que solo has colocado como etiqueta `Sql` en tu pregunta.

En `SQL Server` lo hago de esta manera con una función recursiva:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.factorial ( @numero int )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @i  int

    IF @numero <= 1
        SET @i = 1
    ELSE
        SET @i = @numero * dbo.factorial( @numero - 1 )
RETURN (@i)
END
```

> **Nota:** Como te plantea @Patricio Moracho la parte de utilizar `SMALLINT` te limitaria, también:
>
> - `INT` solo permite hasta factorial de 12.
> - `BIGINT` solo permite hasta factorial de 20.
> - `FLOAT` solo permite hasta factorial de 32 cuando alcanza el límite de recursión.

En esta solución que coloco si deseas puedes usar `BIGINT` y sería una forma de mejorarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, desconocia lo que devolvía cada int, bigint o float